# Dunford Pettis property

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

I am trying the following problem.

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure. Show that an operator $T : L_1(\mu) \rightarrow X$ is Dunford Pettis if and only if $T|_{L_2(\mu)}$ is compact.

I was trying to use the definition. But I cannot come up with anything.Could you give me some hint?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: The Dunford-Pettis property is usually a property of a Banach space, not of a single operator. What do you mean by "Dunford Pettis property of $T$"?

Comment: I had the  same question but a search revealed that an operator is D-P if it maps weakly compact sets to norm compact sets.

Comment: One way is easy: any $L^{2}$ bounded sequence is uniformly integrable, hence weakly relatively compact.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, I got you. How about the other way round?

Comment: This may work: Suppose $(f_n)\subset L_1$ converges weakly to $0$. We need to show $Tf_n$ converges in norm to $0$ (see Prop 5.4.2 in  Albiac/Kalton). Towards this end, fix $M>0$ and   set $g_n=f_n\cdot\chi_{A_n}$ where  $A_n=\{ x  : |f_n (x)|<M\}$. Then  $(g_n)\subset L_2$  and, being a bounded sequence, its image under $T$ tends to $0$ in norm. Since $(f_n)$ is uniformly integrable, $\sup_n \int_{A_n^c } |f_n|$ can be made small (by choosing $M$ large). It seems this will imply the result.

Comment: @DavidMitra, Okay, how does it imply the result?

Comment: $\Vert Tf_n\Vert=\Vert   T(g_n + f_n\cdot\chi_{A_n^c} )\Vert\le\Vert Tg_n\Vert+\Vert T\Vert\Vert  f_n\cdot \chi_{A_n^c} \Vert$.

Comment: @DavidMitra, I think the proof is correct, but there are some places I need a little more clarification, if possible.
1. Why $\|Tg_n\| \rightarrow 0$?
2. Why is $(f_n)$ uniformly integrable?
3. Is it true that $\mu(A_n) < \infty$.

Sorry for asking stupid questions, I am learning, so having some trouble.
Thanks!

Comment: 2. Since $\{\, f_n :n=1,2,\ldots\,\}$ is relatively weakly compact (it's weakly convergent). 3. Yes, since $\mu$ is a probability measure. 1. I'm sorry, but I'm not so sure of this now. I had thought $(g_n)$ was weakly convergent to $0$ (then $(Tg_n)$ would be too; since $T|_{L_2}$ is also compact one could then deduce $(Tg_n)$ converges in norm to $0$). I can't see now why $(g_n)$ should converge weakly to $0$; but I'll think about this some more.

Comment: @DavidMitra, Thanks. Let me know please if you get something for Question 1.

Comment: @DavidMitra, Do you have any idea how to do that?